# Outputting values from List<>

Tags: c#

I want to output each `student.FirstName` from `studentsList` by pressing  `btnNext_Click`, starting from 0 value to the last, by clicking "next button".
I tried to do that but, don't know how to output values correct from `public static List<Student> studentsList = new List<Student>();`

```
private void btnCreateStudent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    addStudent();
    Clear();
}

private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Next();
}

public void addStudent()
{
    Student student = new Student();
    student.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
    student.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
    student.City = txtCity.Text;
    Student.studentsList.Add(student);
}

public void Clear()
{
    txtFirstName.Clear();
    txtLastName.Clear();
    txtCity.Clear();
}

public void Next()
{
    foreach (Student student in Student.studentsList)
    {
        txtFirstName.Text = student.FirstName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming you want to make the button get the next available student every time you click, i would use a Queue and keep dequeuing every time next is called

Comment: get the enumerator, share and reuse it ... anyway, this approach is a bit fragile ...

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to display a single student (that can be changed) or all the students at once?

Comment: @ryanyuyu *starting from 0 value to the last, by clicking "next button"* so I suppose, clicking next should give the next student ... one by one ..

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair yes, I want to add them with - btnCreateStudent_Click and output only first name of each, one by one. On current step i get only last value from list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep the current state inside your program in order to implement "stepping" like that. All you need is the current index, though: initialize it in the constructor, and then use it inside your `Next` method. After you are done with the current index, increment it, so that the next time the `Next` method is called you get a subsequent value.

```
int currentStudent = 0;
public void Clear() {
    txtFirstName.Clear();
    txtLastName.Clear();
    txtCity.Clear();
    currentStudent = 0;
}
public void Next() {
    // You need to stop when you reach the end of the list
    if (currentStudent < Student.studentsList.Count) {
        txtFirstName.Text = Student.studentsList[currentStudent].FirstName;
        currentStudent++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a variable to store the index of the student, and increase it once every time you press next, which will get you the next student name every time.

For example:

```
int studentIndex;
public void Next()
{
     if (studentIndex >= Student.studentsList.Count - 1)
         studentIndex = 0;
     txtFirstName.Text = Student.studentsList[studentIndex].FirstName;
     studentIndex++;
}
```

After you reach the last student, it will reset to the first.

Answer (score 1):

try to store the last index read as a class member.

```
int lastIndexRead = 0;
public void Next()
{
    if(lastIndexRead == Student.studentsList.Count) // do something - index is out of bounds of the array
    else
    {
       txtFirstName.Text = Student.studentsList[lastIndexRead].FirstName;
       lastIndexRead++;
   }
}
```